# Makefile Errors

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, makefile

I've been trying to compile this makefile on my mac and it is bringing up a particular error.

First, here is the folder that the makefile is in:
http://www.zezula.net/download/stormlib.zip
That is a direct download link. It contains a file, "Makefile.mac", that I'm trying to run.

So I installed Command Line Tools through XCode, and then I used:

```
cd ~/Downloads/StormLib/
make -f Makefile.mac
```

It showed an error:

```
Makefile.mac:87: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
```

And yes, I've searched for the solution to this. It says to add a tab beforehand. So I tried that, and this is what it showed:

```
Makefile.mac:87: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

I looked up that error, and one of the solutions involved having spaces instead of tabs. So now I'm just confused. What should I do to fix it? This is what line 87 looks like:

```
src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utctime.obj \
```

Thanks for any and all help.

EDIT: Here is the makefile:
http://pastebin.com/KSba5fUv

A version of the makefile with some lines deleted and line 87 marked is:

```
[9 lines deleted]

CPP    = g++
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
LFLAGS = -lbz2 -lz -framework Carbon
ARCH = -arch x86_64
DFLAGS = -D__SYS_BZLIB -D__SYS_ZLIB -D_7ZIP_ST
AR     = ar
ARFLAGS= rcs

LIBRARY  = libStorm.dylib

OBJS_CPP = src/adpcm/adpcm.obj \
           src/huffman/huff.obj \
[15 lines deleted]
           src/SFileReadFile.obj \
           src/SFileVerify.obj


OBJS_C   = src/jenkins/lookup3.o \
           src/libtomcrypt/src/hashes/hash_memory.obj \
[39 lines deleted]
           src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_sequence.obj \
           src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_short_integer.obj \
       \
       src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utctime.obj \         # This is line 87
       \  
           src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utf8_string.obj \
       \  
           src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_sequence_free.obj \
       \  
           src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/ecc/ltc_ecc_map.obj \
           src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/ecc/ltc_ecc_mul2add.obj \
[135 lines deleted]
           src/pklib/explode.obj \
           src/pklib/implode.obj

all: $(LIBRARY)

[8 lines deleted]

$(LIBRARY): $(OBJS_C) $(OBJS_CPP)
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) $(ARCH) $(LFLAGS) -shared -o $(LIBRARY) $(OBJS_C) $(OBJS_CPP)
#   $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(LIBRARY) $(OBJS_C) $(OBJS_CPP)

$(OBJS_C): %.obj: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) -c $<

$(OBJS_CPP): %.obj: %.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: I don't see how anyone could fix your problem without seeing your code

Comment: You really need to post at least a couple of lines around line 87 [perhaps 5-10 lines before and 5-10 lines after].

Comment: in the future you might get better answers if you just post the relative line(s) of your code here, on the site, instead of making people download a file, extracting, and opening.  If you are not inclined to post it on this site you might also use a site like pastie to put it online somewhere.

Comment: You'll need to show a few lines either side of line 87. It might be that you're missing a backslash on a previous line.

Comment: looking at the code, you should try escaping your blank lines on lines  86, 88, 90, 92, or remove them entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to escape your blank lines, or remove them entirely:

```
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_sequence.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_short_integer.obj \

   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utctime.obj \

   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utf8_string.obj \

   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_sequence_free.obj \

   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/ecc/ltc_ecc_map.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/ecc/ltc_ecc_mul2add.obj \
```

becomes

```
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_sequence.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_short_integer.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utctime.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utf8_string.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_sequence_free.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/ecc/ltc_ecc_map.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/ecc/ltc_ecc_mul2add.obj \
```

or (this might not work, haven't tested it, but it should)

```
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_sequence.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_short_integer.obj \
   \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utctime.obj \
   \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_length_utf8_string.obj \
   \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/asn1/der_sequence_free.obj \
   \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/ecc/ltc_ecc_map.obj \
   src/libtomcrypt/src/pk/ecc/ltc_ecc_mul2add.obj \
```

Comment: Thank you. That appeared to get rid of that error. And I apologize, I should've put the makefile on pastebin.
Here it is for anyone who needs it:
http://pastebin.com/KSba5fUv